# RefineryCMS with mutliple associated model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I searched everything about how to generate association between two or more model using "RefineryCMS". I followed everything from this URL https://github.com/refinery .
I want to create two model with association.

Anyone can please help me

Comment: Hi @pratik can you explain how did you solve this please?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to relate models from two different refinery engines you can do something like this. Suppose you have a User engine and a Post engine and you want to define user has_many posts between the models of these two engines.

In the user.rb in the User engine add

```
has_many :posts, :class_name => Refinery::Posts::Post
```

and in the post.rb add

```
belongs_to :user, :class_name => Refinery::Users::User
```